# Can 2 CSS Media Query definition overlap

Tags: iphone, ipad, css, media-queries

I am defining multiple CSS Media Queries for different vieqport or device widths...

So my question is can 2 CSS Media Query definition blocks overlap OR only 1st match gets applied. How does it work ?

Also what is the correct method to apply for multiple devices..i mean the order of defining ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you can combine multiple media queries in a comma-separated list; if
>   any of the media queries in the list is true, the associated style
>   sheet is applied.  This is the equivalent of a logical "or" operation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

So

> This is the equivalent of a logical "or" operation

makes it look like only one match is applied.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/mediaqueries seems to confirm this as well.

If this is true (and it is untested by me), then I would create a common stylesheet to deliver all the common styles no matter what media query is matched and then have device independent stylesheets with additional styles for each targeted device.

Comment: Thx a lot..but my question is if i have multiple @media statements in my css for different min max widths , is there any possibility that 2 of these blocks get applied OR only 1 will be applied..pls provide any examples..

Comment: According to the docs I provided, only one can be applied.  Untested, though.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer just now... could you explain why? I don't mind being downvoted if it warrants it, but I like to know why. I don't want to make the same mistakes in the future.

Comment: Some people think they're too much of a jerk and so want to decrease their reputation by decreasing others' reputation without a valid reason. Anyway, while it's a logical OR operation, it's not necessarily a logical XOR (exclusive OR) operation, so multiple media queries could apply at the same time, just as `div#foo` and `#foo` would both match the same element. Your answer seems reasonable to me otherwise, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird. If you write:

```
<link media="screen and (max-width: 1250px)" href="/css/small.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="screen and (max-height: 850px)" href="/css/small.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

It acts like a XOR (having 2 stylesheets). If both conditions are met (width < 1250 AND height < 850) the stylesheet is not applied.
But if you write:

```
<link media="screen and (max-width: 1250px), screen and (max-height: 850px)" href="/css/small.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

It works fine. So comma is the solution for everything.